# How can I listen for second click in gesture detector in Flutter?

Tags: button, flutter, dart, onclick, listener

I want to create a button with a gesture detector, and I want to listen for the second click from the user on this button.

I want to do something like this:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onSecondTap: () {
    // My code
  }
  child: FlatButton(),
), // GestureDetector
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244113/can-i-change-right-click-action-in-flutter-web-application also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GestureDetector has the `onDoubleTap` listener. This will be trigger if the user double clicks the widget within certain amount of time.

```dart
GestureDetector(
    onDoubleTap: () {
        // Your code here
    }
...
```

Comment: it isn't what I want, I want to listen the next click in any time such as maybe after minutes, seconds, etc,

Comment: so you just use a single click and save the amount of clicks in the state.