# How to make context menu for chrome extension with flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, dart, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to trigger context menu in chrome extension with Flutter? I searched all around the website and I didn't see it. All I want to do is that hit the mouse's right click and appear context box like "Search Google For bla bla". [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change right click action in flutter web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244113/can-i-change-right-click-action-in-flutter-web-application)